# $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}e^{-z}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I was wondering if the following limit can be evaluated:
$$\lim_{|z|\to\infty}e^{-z}$$
My first instinct was not, as $e^{-z}\to 0$ is only true for $\Re(z)\to\infty$ since $\Im(z)$ would just fluctuate with $0\le e^{\Im(z)}\le1$. So my question is to define this limit correctly and assume it tends to zero would we have to say something like:
$$z=x+jy\,\,\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}e^{-(x+jy)}=0$$

Comment: Just realised I missed a minus sign in the final line, I have corrected it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and very badly so. The exponential function has an essential singularity at infinity, which means it assumes all but finitely many values of $\mathbb C$ in every neighborhood (so infinitely often) of the singularity.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not ! take $x_n=2in\pi$ and $y_n=n$ to conclude the non existence.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in $z_n=-n$ which satisfies $|z|\rightarrow\infty$.  So we're having a bad day.

Answer (score 1):

Approach along the negative $x-$axis starting from the origin i.e. $x\rightarrow-\infty$ and $y=0$.